# Cordova SQLite Return a Promise?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, promise, cordova-sqlite-storage

Consider this method in an angular service:

```
    select : function(table) {
        window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
            name: 'smartLab.db',
            location: 'default'
        }, function success(db) {
            var defer = window.Q.defer();

            console.dir(defer);

            db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM ' + table, [], function success(rows) {
                var resp = [];

                for(var i = 0; i < rows.rows.length; i++) {
                    resp.push(rows.rows.item(i));
                }

                defer.resolve(resp);

            }, defer.reject)
        }, function error(err) {

        })
    }
```

I am calling it from another service in the following way:

```
DatabaseService.select(TBL_NAME).then(function(rows) {
  // logic goes here
});
```

The error I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

I have never used Q before but am familiar with promises, anything jump out as being inherently wrong?  Clearly something is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are never returning the promise from the defered object (click [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/master/README.md#using-deferreds) for more)

```
select : function(table) {
    var defer = window.Q.defer();

    window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
        name: 'smartLab.db',
        location: 'default'
    }, function success(db) {


        console.dir(defer);

        db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM ' + table, [], function success(rows) {
            var resp = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < rows.rows.length; i++) {
                resp.push(rows.rows.item(i));
            }

            defer.resolve(resp);

        }, defer.reject)
    }, function error(err) {

    });

    return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: Clearly something was inherently wrong!  Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using ionic/angular you can also use a `Promise`. For example I use a DataProvider Directive:

```
public getJobs() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.sqlite.create({
        name: this.dbName,
        location: this.dbLoc
      })
      .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        var query = "SELECT * FROM user_jobs WHERE user_id=(?)";
        db.executeSql(query, [this.userId])
        .then((resp) => {
          console.log('Executed SELECT SQL:', resp.rows.length);
          resolve(resp);
        })
        .catch(e => console.log('db.executeSql error: ', JSON.stringify(e)));

      })
      .catch(e => console.log('sqlite.create error: ', e));

      });
  }
```

In any page you can call easily call it:

```
this.dataProvider.getJobs().then((resp:any) => {
        if (resp.rows.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < resp.rows.length; i++) {
            let item = resp.rows.item(i);
            console.log(item);
          }
        }
      });
```